# unable to read data from JSON, using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am making an ajax call like

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "updateDistributionData",
  data: {
    userId: userid
  },
  //if received a response from the server
  success: function(data) {
    //  $('#add-distribution tbody').empty();
    console.log(data);

    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      var html = '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + value.year + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + value.month + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';

      $('#update-distribution tr').first().after(html);
    });
  }
});
```

which return the below JSON

```
{
  "respData": [
    {
      "salesTargetId": "c51a411e-44ed-496c-85c0-52d76bd97c64",
      "userId": "5f32aa84-c9e7-4c27-a292-0f06ffe07b82",
      "type": "SALES",
      "month": "April",
      "year": "2021",
      "target": 1550,
      "actual": 500,
      "createdBy": "5f32aa84-c9e7-4c27-a292-0f06ffe07b82",
      "createdDate": "2021-05-06 15:51:41",
      "brand": "Cipla",
      "status": "ACTIVE"
    },
    {
      "salesTargetId": "d2053e0a-c0b4-4adf-bf98-05789cb8f72f",
      "userId": "5f32aa84-c9e7-4c27-a292-0f06ffe07b82",
      "type": "SALES",
      "month": "April",
      "year": "2021",
      "target": 3000,
      "actual": 1000,
      "createdBy": "5f32aa84-c9e7-4c27-a292-0f06ffe07b82",
      "createdDate": "2021-05-06 16:07:41",
      "brand": "Glaxo",
      "status": "ACTIVE"
    }
  ]
}
```

but I am getting the below error on the console

> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1601' in {"respData":[{"salesTargetId":"c51a411e-44ed-496c-85c0-52d76bd97c64","userId":"5f32aa84-c9e7-4c27-a292-0f06ffe07b82","type":"SALES","month":"April","year":"2021","target":1550,"actual":500,"createdBy":"5f32aa84-c9e7-4c27-a292-0f06ffe07b82","createdDate":"2021-05-06 15:51:41","brand":"Cipla","status":"ACTIVE"},{"salesTargetId":"d2053e0a-c0b4-4adf-bf98-05789cb8f72f","userId":"5f32aa84-c9e7-4c27-a292-0f06ffe07b82","type":"SALES","month":"April","year":"2021","target":3000,"actual":1000,"createdBy":"5f32aa84-c9e7-4c27-a292-0f06ffe07b82","createdDate":"2021-05-06 16:07:41","brand":"Glaxo","status":"ACTIVE"}]}

Please help

Comment: i mean... Why are you calling `.each` on an object and not the array that object contains?

Comment: `$.each(data` is going to bring back `"respData"` as `key` and the array as `value`. You likely want to do `$.each(data.respData`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey, based on your comment I updated  $.each(data.respData, function(key, value) now am getting . Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: This is where you need to use your skills as a programmer to debug the code. Set breakpoints, look at the data coming back. Apparently, you are not actually receiving the data you say you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your data is not parsed into an object but still a string.
Set the dataType to json to have it parsed to an object.
Also you should be looping through the respData array

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "updateDistributionData",
  data: {
    userId: userid
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  //if received a response from the server
  success: function(data) {
    //  $('#add-distribution tbody').empty();
    console.log(data);

    $.each(data.respData, function(key, value) {
      var html = '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + value.year + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + value.month + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';

      $('#update-distribution tr').first().after(html);
    });
  }
});
```